# (Pycharm) ImportError: No module named sklearn

Tags: pycharm, importerror

I'm trying to import SVC from sklearn.svm and got "ImportError: No module named sklearn" although the scikit-learn package was installed. What is happening and how to fix it?

Thank you.

[image: Installed package]

[image: ImportError]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaI0K.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEnco.png

Comment: Did you restart the Python Console after having installed scikit-learn

Comment: yes, I tried it multiple times and it is still having that problem